# Android Image Adapter, Return an integer in getCount()

Tags: android, arrays, gridview

I'm using an image adapter to randomly place images into a gridview, I have 3 different image arrays and it sources the images from one of the arrays depending on an integer I have. I want the number of images that it displays in the gridview to be different depending on which array it is getting them from, so I figured I need to change this code

`public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}`

So how do I make this return an integer or a different array based on my int?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
            randomPosition = hold.nextInt(gridSize);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3); 
            } 
            else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imgSet();
            return imageView;
    }

    public void imgSet(){
        if (diff == 1){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 2){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds2[randomPosition]);
        }
        if (diff == 3){
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds3[randomPosition]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please elaborate your code and question

Comment: We cannot find any solution for this question elaborate it.

Comment: I don't see how I can elaborate on this question it is put very clearly, all I want to know is how change the amount of times the image adapter will loop so that I can set how many images it will place into the gridview rather than using the length of the mThumbIds array.

Comment: Please show your code that how you are passing different arrays into your adapter ? By reading your content no one would provide you exact answer. @MDubzem

Comment: @MDubzem I asked to post the code where are binding your data into adapter.

Comment: So do you want my arrays? They are pretty big, they are called mThumbIds, mThumbIds2 and mThumbIds3. The first one has 16 drawables, the second has 25 and the third has 36.

Comment: I want to see how your are passing each one by one?

Comment: Thats what the Image adapter does... it loops adding the images to the gridview until it has reached the amount of images in the array specified in getCount(). I want to dynamically change the array specified depending on an int value.